# Creating a contour plot in paraview from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, paraview, mayavi

I have a large binary file that contains all the information I want to plot. The data is ordered in such a way that its easiest to read into a 3D numpy array, this worked fine when I was using Mayavi to plot it using the [contour3d()](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html) function. Now I'm using Paraview and I can't find any examples of how I could accomplish the same thing. It seems like the only way to get data in is to read it directly from a file in one of many formats and not a numpy array. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, `mayavi` is build on [`tvtk`](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/wiki/TVTK), a wrapper of `vtk` designed for `Traits` support and an easier handling of NumPy.

`ParaView` on the other hand is based on pure `vtk`, which makes it a tad less straightforward to manipulate `ndarrays` directly. However, some support functions are readily available:

```
>>> from vtk.util import numpy_support as npvtk
>>> vtkarray = npvtk.numpy_to_vtk(numpy_array)
>>> numpy_array = npvtk.vtk_to_numpy(vtkarray)
```

More reading:

- the [examples](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/vtkWithNumpy) from the `vtk` wiki  are always a good start.
- the [vtk mailing list archive](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Python-numpy-array-gt-vtkImage-gt-paraview-td5551250.html) can also help you.

Comment: In case anyone's interested there is a similar method: `from paraview.vtk.dataset_adapter import numpyTovtkDataArray` on there [wiki](http://paraview.org/Wiki/index.php?title=ParaView/Users_Guide/Python_Programmable_Filter)

Comment: As it turns out `numpyTovtkDataArray` only supports 2D arrays, which isn't very helpful for my situation.